# How to upload the file into HttpFileCollection in C# Unit Test

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

```
var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)
{
    var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[0];
```

I want to upload the file to `HttpFileCollection` in unit test MVC C#, And to get the file in I have mentined function,

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
      HttpResponseMessage result = null;
      var httpRequest = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request;
      HttpFileCollection uploadFiles = httpRequest.Files;
      var uploadedReportFiles = new List<string>();
     //Check if files are there
      if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0){
          int i;
          for (i = 0; i < uploadFiles.Count; i++) 
          {
              // Get the file from collection
              HttpPostedFile postedFile = uploadFiles[i];
              var filePath = @"C:/inetpub/wwwroot/uploaded/reports/" + postedFile.FileName;
              postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);
              uploadedReportFiles.Add(filePath);
          }
          result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, uploadedReportFiles);
      } else {
          result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
      }
    
      return result;
```

Comment: I want to upload the files to HttpFileCollection to get the mock files for if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0) and how to upload and get this httpRequest.Files; for unit test